# capistrano upload! thinks ~ referenced local directory is on remote server

Tags: deployment, capistrano

So every example I've looked up indicates this is how one is supposed to do it but I think I may have found a bug unless there's another way to do this.
I'm using upload! to upload assets to a remote list of servers.  The task looks like this:

```
  desc "Upload grunt compiled css/js."
  task :upload_assets do
    on roles(:all) do 
      %w{/htdocs/css /htdocs/js}.each do |asset|
          upload! "#{fetch(:local_path) + asset}", "#{release_path.to_s + '/' + asset}", recursive: true
      end
    end
  end
```

If **local_path** is defined as an absolute path such as:

```
set :local_path:,  '/home/dcmbrown/projects/ABC'
```

This works fine.  However if I do the following:

```
set :local_path:,  '~/projects/ABC'
```

I end up getting the error:

```
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on ec2-54-23-88-125.us-west-2.compute.amazon.com: No such file or directory - ~/projects/ABC/htdocs/css
```

It's not a ' vs " issue as I've tried both (and I didn't think capistrano paid attention to that anyway).

Is this a bug?  Is there a work around? Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up discovering the best way to do this is to actually use path expansion! (headsmack)

```
irb> File.expand_path('~dcmbrown/projects/ABC')
=> "/home/dcmbrown/projects/ABC"
```

Of course what I'd like is to do automatic path expansion but you can't have everything.  I think I was mostly dumbstruck that it didn't automatically; so much so I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why it didn't work and ended up wasting time asking here. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is coming from the remote server, it just looks like it since it's running that upload command in the context of a deploy.

I just created a single cap task to just do an upload using the "~" character and it also fails with

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@XXX: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - ~/Projects/testapp/public/404.html
```

It appears to be a Ruby issue not Capistrano as this also fails in a Ruby console

```
~/Projects/testapp $ irb
2.2.2 :003 > File.stat('~/Projects/testapp/public/404.html')

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - ~/Projects/testapp/public/404.html
from (irb):3:in `stat'
from (irb):3
from /Users/supairish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```